# Задать стиль для одного пункта SELECT

Tags: css3

Есть выпадающий список и нужно задать отступы, верхнюю границу только для одного пункта из всего списка. Присвоила класс, работает только бекграунд. Задаю границу, отступы, ничего не отображается.

```css
.non-eu {
  background:#ccc;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Select Your country...</option>
  <option>Albania</option>
  <option>Austria</option>
  <option>Belgium</option>
  <option>Bosnia And Herzegovina</option>
  <option class="non-eu">Non-EU</option>
 </select>
```

Как можно решить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По-умолчанию выпадающий список в селекте рендерится операционной системой. Это позволяет, например, на мобильных устройствах показывать список селекта вместо экранной клавиатуры.

Через CSS стилизовать можно только само поле стандартного селекта, список - нельзя.

Однако можно подключить js-библиотеку для селекта. Например, [select2](https://select2.github.io/). Она заменяет стандартный инпут-селект своей реализацией, и ее - можно стилизовать в CSS.

В версии 4.0 select2 - отдельная опция стилизуется так:

```
function template(result, container) {
  var option_class = $(result.element).attr('class');
  if (option_class) {
    $(container).addClass(option_class);
  }
  return result.text;
};

$(document).bind('ready', function() {
  $('.js-select2').select2({
    templateResult: template
  });
});
```

В функции `template` мы проверяем, задан ли класс у стандартного `option` у селекта, и, если да - применяем этот класс к опции select2.